# Replace string plus brackets around it is not working with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string with multiple occurrences of a key like this

```
var str = '[a] is a string with many [a] but only one [b]';
```

now I have an object with keys with their values in str;

```
var obj = {a:'the a',b:'the b'};
```

I tried like this replacing those keys with their values

```
let output = str;
for (const key in obj) {
      output = output.replace(new RegExp('[[' + key + ']]', 'g'), obj[key]);
    }
```

its output is

```
[the a is a string with many [the a but only one [the b
```

can any body tell what I am missing?

**Edit**

How can I replace `@[a](a)` with `the a` and `@[b](b)` with `the b`? i.e.

```
 var str = '@[a](a) is a string with many @[a](a) but only one @[b](b)';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using this code:

```js
var str = '@[a](a) is a string with many @[a](a) but only one @[b](b)';
var obj = {a:'the a',b:'the b'};

let output = str;
for (const key in obj) {
   output = output.replace(new RegExp('@\\[' + key + '\\]\\(' + key + '\\)', 'g'), obj[key]);
}

console.log(output);
//=> "the a is a string with many the a but only one the b"
```

`[` must be escaped in Javascript regex and when using `RegExp` constructer escape it twice.

Comment: Sure, let me take a look. btw you don't need to unmark my answer to ask further enhancements. I always try my level best to answer all the queries.

Comment: check my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Example `[[a]]`

matches either `[]` or `a]`  because it parses to

```
 [[a]            # Class, '[' or 'a'
 ]               # followed by ']'
```

To fix it, escape the outer bracket literals so they are literals.

`output = output.replace(new RegExp('\\[[' + key + ']\\]', 'g'), obj[key]);`

and you could even get rid of the inner *class* brackets, since there is only 1 key each pass.

`output = output.replace(new RegExp('\\[' + key + '\\]', 'g'), obj[key]);`

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch - Beware leaving literal class brackets un-escaped. The designers of regex long ago left the trailers that could be literals not having to be escaped. It's a bad habit that will bite you when regex gets more complex.

Comment: I just got another problem, `@[a](a)` how to replace this with `the a`. I dont want to post another question for it.

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch - l probably know the answer, but you've already selected an answer. Try to as him.

Comment: he answered in 2 minutes, it was unfair at that to select yours. but now I have undo his answer. go on with the solution :-)